The run destination Devendra’s iPhone is not valid for Running the scheme 'Runner'
can snyone help me to fix the error "The run destination Devendra’s iPhone is not valid for Running the scheme 'Runner'"
Could not locate device support files You may be able to resolve the issue by installing the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store or developer.apple.com.
[missing string: 869a8e318f07f3e2f42e11d435502286094f76de]

Want to fix the error

What version of iOS is on the phone?  What version of Xcode do you have?

Most likely you have an iPhone with iOS 17.x which requires Xcode 15+ otherwise Xcode can't talk to your iPhone.

My iPhone iOS version is 17.5.1 but I'm using MacBook Air (macOS Monterey) with version 12.7.5 and the current Xcode Version is 14.2 (14C18).
Also, my MacBook is up-to-date.
